# Определить падеж прилагательных

Tags: морфология

*Мелкий  снег едва припорошил  степь. Овцы медленно брели по бескрайней степи.Черные жаворонки порхали у ног овец. Вдруг они с тревожным писком заметались. Старый чабан внимательно посмотрел на взволнованных птиц. Он быстро погнал овец в кошару. Черные жаворонки предупредили об опасности.Вскоре начался сильный буран. Задержались бы овцы в степи — не миновать беды.*

Answer (score 2):

Мелкий(И.п.) снег едва припорошил степь. Овцы медленно брели по бескрайней (Д.п.) степи.Черные (И.п.) жаворонки порхали у ног овец. Вдруг они с тревожным (Т.п.) писком заметались. Старый (И.П.) чабан внимательно посмотрел на взволнованных (Р.П.) птиц. Он быстро погнал овец в кошару. Черные (И.П.) жаворонки предупредили об опасности.Вскоре начался сильный (и.п.) буран. Задержались бы овцы в степи-не миновать беды.

Answer (score 1):

мелкий — им. п. снег едва припорошил степь.Овцы медленно брели по бескрайней д.п. степи.Черные и.п. жаворонки порхали у ног овец.Вдруг они с тревожным т. в. писком заметались.Старый и.п. чабан внимательно посмотрел на (кого? что?) взволнованных в.п.  птиц.Он быстро погнал овец в кошару.Черные и.п.  жаворонки предупредили об опасности.Вскоре начался сильный и.п. буран.Задержались бы овцы в степи-не миновать беды.